# How to generate dynamic MultipleChoiceField options on page2 according to choice on page1?

Tags: python, django, forms, dynamic

I am writing 2 pages. What I want to do is, according to the data selected in page1, generate a form with MultipleChoiceField having options calculated by page1 result. Or to read according file is also fine, just to get the options for MultipleChoiceField in page2 form.

I am using the form template, and in forms.py, in the form class in page2,

```
class FormPage2(forms.Form): 
    forms.MultipleChoiceField(label='sth to choose',choices=get_tochoose_choices())
```

the get_tochoose_choices() is reading some txt file to get the options.

But when I load the first page,(I think python instantiate all forms no matter if it's on this page or not together) this file doesn't exist, which means the FormPage2 cannot be instantiated. Even the file is there, it's not the uptodate one.

Then what should I do? I am quite new to website design and hope someone could help...

Comment: Something like here? http://blogs.sourceallies.com/2012/04/multi-step-forms-in-django/

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're trying to do is build your second form dynamically based on the options selected in the first.

I had to do something similar for one of my projects and found this link very userful: http://jacobian.org/writing/dynamic-form-generation/

You need to override the `__init__` method of the second method and thus initialize the options during the initialization of that form.

Your code for the second form should have something like this..

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    #first remove my custom keyword from the list of keyword args
    try:
        customer = kw['customer']
        kw.pop('customer')
    except:
        customer=None

    super(forms.Form, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
    #now we dynamically add the customer choices - accepts partners as an input
    partners = get_partner_list(customerid=customer.id)
    self.fields['customer'].choices = [(p.id, p.customername) for p in partners]
```

After receiving the input from the first form, you can pass that as a keyword argument to the second form.
Then in the `__init__` of the second form you pop out that keyword argument and use it to initialize the choices by editing `self.fields['fieldneedsdynamicchoices'].choices`

Comment: Thank you very much and I got the idea. I made it by override the __init__. But, btw, do you know how does the default __init__ work? why after I override it and set self.fields["to_choose"] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=get_tochoose_choices()), it wouldn't instantiate at the time I load page1 but if I didn't override the default __init__ it would do so? Thanks again!

Comment: Did you mean to say that the other way round? That the options instantiate when you override and not when you don't. If you meant something else, could you clarify that further. I'm not sure I fully understood you.

Comment: I mean the default __init__ in the class initialize all forms no matter if it's in page1 or page2 to produce the html(even at first I just load page1, and it reports an error about the form on page2 cannot get data), but after overriding it initialize form on page2 when generating page2. How could this happen? how does the default __init__ works? Thanks, I hope you know what I mean...